# Alias an entire table's fields

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I am querying/joining two tables, each with certain identical field names:

```
SELECT * FROM sales1 s1 JOIN sales2 s2 USING (id)
```

Is it possible to prefix the columns for each table with the tablename (or some other prefix), so for example instead of getting data such as:

```
id   id    product     product    etc.
```

It looks like:

```
s1_id     s2_id     s1_product       s2_product     etc.
```

Without doing it manually for every single field?

Comment: Other than dynamic SQL, I don't think so.

Comment: No. Do it manually. How hard is it?

Comment: Outside of "dev" queries, you really should be explicitly selecting the needed fields rather than using `*`. When you're not skipping that work, aliasing isn't really much more effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL you can do:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM sales1 s1 JOIN sales2 s2 USING (id);
```

Followed by:

```
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

That will show you a rewritten version of the original query with quoted, fully qualified column and table names like so:

```
/* select#1 */ select `dbname`.`s1`.`id` AS `id`,`dbname`.`s1`.`product` AS `product`,`dbname`.`s2`.`product` AS `product` from `dbname`.`sales1` `s1` join `dbname`.`sales2` `s2` where (`dbname`.`s2`.`id` = `dbname`.`s1`.`id`)
```

You then need to do some regex find-replace afterwards. So yes, do it manually.

Comment: that looks perfect. What's wrong with using the above? Using it as-is without doing any regex replacement?

Comment: For me there is just too much noise. I would at least remove the database names. And notice that the JOIN condition is rewritten as a WHERE clause.

Comment: @David542 also, if you look at the sql, it still uses the same alias for both table references' fields; you still get `(id, product, product)` for your results. ...and as Salman said, having `dbname` bumping your character count by a significant percentage does not help readability.